# TOP cpu %ulitization exceeds number of procs X 100%

Tags: linux, top

I have a VM with 2 virtual CPUs.  When I run two multi-threaded java proceses the total CPU utilization in top exceeds 200%.  In fact its closer to 800%.
  [alt text http://ftp.lib.byu.edu/top.jpg](http://ftp.lib.byu.edu/top.jpg)

I thought that %CPU was the percentage utilization of one core, and that a process on a two core box couldn't exceed 200 %CPU.  Am I wrong?

Comment: Top within the VM or on the host machine?

Comment: Also, what VM technology?

Comment: Its a VM running on ESX.  The top screen is running on the VM.

Comment: This is possibly a dupe of http://serverfault.com/questions/71510/cpu-for-a-process or http://serverfault.com/questions/29231/confused-by-cpu-values-in-unix-top-command

Answer (score 2):

Does it make any more since when using the -H option (Press Shift-H while running), to show threads?  Then see the "What to look for from the top -H output" [from this IBM link](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/tools/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.java.doc.igaa/_1vg0001475cb4a-1190e2e0f74-8000_1007.html).

Comment: @Kyle - It does make more since when using the H option.  Thanks for the tip.